# Not getting data in swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: get data
  description: About  -  API allows you to easily automate the buy/sell process within the  environment.
servers:
- url: "tatr/v1/api"
paths:
  /getAllClients:
    get:
      summary: Retrieve all clients
      description: Endpoint to fetch all client data
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: Ts_Token
        description: Token for authentication
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  success:
                    type: boolean
                  apiVersion:
                    type: integer
                  message:
                    type: string
                  result:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      status:
                        type: integer
                      data:
                        type: array
                        items:
                          type: object
                          properties:
                            Id:
                              format: int64
                              type: integer
                              example: 134
                            ClientGUID:
                              type: string
                              example: "2107133f-6d99-418d-b97d-4707f4daadce"
                            ClientName:
                              type: string
                            EmailAddress:
                              type: string
                            ContactNumber:
                              type: string
                            Address:
                              type: string
                            CompanyName:
                              type: string
                            Country:
                              type: integer
                            GSTNo:
                              type: string
                            IsCGST:
                              type: integer
                            IsSGST:
                              type: integer
                            IsActive:
                              type: integer
                            IsTest:
                              type: integer
                      totalCount:
                        type: integer
                      message:
                        type: string
        '401':
          description: Bad Request
```

I'm trying to get all the data from my backend but i not getting data please check whats wrong with this code

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. There's nothing wrong with your OpenAPI definition. Please post the code you have written to implement the API server, the code you have written to implement the API client, and any errors you are getting. Thank you